# Is there a way to join dynamically generated subtitles to a video to make them permanent so that the user can download the video with the subtitles?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, html5-video

I am working with a web application using Node.js and Express, and I display a video with some subtitles generated dynamically. I was wondering if there was a way to integrate this subtitles in the video so that the user could download this new video.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

As you said, the subtitles are dynamic and are not 'baked' into the video. You'd have to re-render the video with the subtitles in order to ship them together.

A solution might be to zip the video alongside with a subtitle file (.srt) so that the user can view them with a video player like VLC. This also gives you the option to add multiple languages for example.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to transcode/transmux the video in ffmpeg or some other tool. Ideally you'd create your subtitles in SRT or webvtt format, then add them to the video file: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i subtitles.srt -c copy video_with_subtitles.mp4`. Or you could ["burn" them into the video](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1), but that's usually not the preferred experience.